# When parsing a text file with a Scanner why am I getting null characters between each expected character?

Tags: java, file-io, null, registry, java.util.scanner

I am creating a registry snapshot with the command:
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("REG EXPORT HKLM " + pathVariable + "\HKLM.txt /y");

I am then parsing through this file trying to group the registry entries into a single String as they are often broken up over multiple lines.  When I use this bit of code I am always getting the "NUL" character for every even character.

```
String line, concatLine;
Scanner scanner;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
    line = null;
    concatLine = "";
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(line !=null && !(line.isEmpty())){
            concatLine += line;
        }
        else if(!(concatLine.equals(""))){
            System.out.println(concatLine);
            concatLine = "";
        }
            }
} catch (IOException e) {//Catch I/O Exceptions
            System.err.println(e);
}
```

I am looking at the file before scanning it in NP++ and there are no "NUL" characters, but if I write these concatenated lines to a file the entire file has them between each expected character.

Comment: The file is encoded using a multi-byte character set. Your scanner is reading one byte at a time, thinking it is reading an ASCII encoded file.

Comment: check the character encoding of the file. it's possible the file is encoded as UTF-16 while your scanner is expecting it to be ANSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my search to understand the problem I came across [Java reading and writing paractices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42)  which is definitely worth looking over. Apart from that, it seems like the early comments were correct. If the file is opened as a UTF-16 stream, and written as such, then the output is without the null characters. By the way, you will also need to deal with escaped newlines in registry dump, because if you don't you will end up with things like: "00,00,\  00," where you should have "00,00,00,".

Here is an example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class ReadReg {
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        String line=null; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner scanner; 
        FileOutputStream fos; 
        BufferedOutputStream bos; OutputStreamWriter fosw;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("hklm-hw.txt"), "UTF-16");
            fos  = new FileOutputStream("hklm-hw.cat.txt");
            bos  = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            fosw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "UTF-16");
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append( line = scanner.nextLine());
                if (line.isEmpty()) {
                    sb.append("\n");
                }
            }
            if (null != scanner.ioException()) {
                out.format("scanner ioe:\n\t%s\n", scanner.ioException().getMessage());
                //scanner.ioException().printStackTrace();
            }
            fosw.write( sb.toString(), 0, sb.length());
            fosw.flush();
            fosw.close();
            scanner.close();
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Output:

```
$ javac ReadReg.java  && java ReadReg ; file *
hklm-hw.cat.txt: Big-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines
hklm-hw.txt:     Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF, CR line terminators
ReadReg.class:   compiled Java class data, version 50.0 (Java 1.6)
ReadReg.java:    C source, ASCII text
```